# Show the integral $\lim_{B\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^B \sin(x)\sin(x^2)\,dx$ converges

Tags: contest-math, solution-verification

> Show the integral $$\lim_{B\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^B \sin(x)\sin(x^2)\,dx$$ converges.

I guess we should use the equality $$\sin(x)\sin(x^2)=\dfrac{1}{2}[-\cos(x+x^2)+\cos(x-x^2)],$$ so we have $$\sin(x)\sin(x^2)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}C(2n,2m)x^{2m}.$$
Am I right?

Comment: $\sin(x)\sin(x^2)=\dfrac{1}{2}[-\cos(x+x^2)+\cos(x-x^2)],$

Comment: it should be an answer :-)

Comment: @idm I was just pointing out the mistake :) integrating by parts once should complete it.

Comment: okay I may be going insane but it isn't a necessary condition for the integral to converge that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(x) \sin(x^2) = 0$?

Comment: @Ant No, that's for sums. E.g. $0=\int_0^\infty\chi_{x\in\mathbb N}$ converges (and can be easily modified for a continuous function).

Comment: @user2345215 holy cow. I was absolutely convinced it was true. Have to look into that!

Comment: @user2345215 however if the limit exists then it equals $0$, correct?

Comment: @Ant Yes.​​​​​​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change variables
$$\int \cos(x+x^2)dx = \int\frac{\cos(y)}{\sqrt{4y+1}}dy\\
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}\cos(y)(4y+1)^{-1/2}dy\\
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sin(y)(4y+1)^{-1/2}|_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}+\int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}\sin(y)2(4y+1)^{-3/2}dy\\
\leq 0+\sum_n4\pi(8n\pi+1)^{-3/2}<\infty$$